# MP4 date on windows 10 explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp4, exif, exiftool

I have several MP4 videos.
On windows explorer, under the column "Date", I see the wrong time stamp, it is always 3 hours LATER than the EXIF fields:

```
QuickTime:CreateDate
QuickTime:ModifyDate
QuickTime:TrackCreateDate
QuickTime:TrackModifyDate
QuickTime:MediaCreateDate
QuickTime:MediaModifyDate
```

The actual time of the video is the date in the EXIF fields plus 4 hours.

What is the reason for this offset?

Comment: Is it not part of the meta data?
Can it be controlled?

Comment: I don't see the same behaviour for jpg file for example.
What appears in the EXIF meta data is EXACTLY what windows explorer shows under "date" with no offsets

Comment: I don't follow, these are digital camera videos. I just want them to show the real date.

Comment: What is the timezone the videos were taken in?

According to the specs, those timestamps are supposed to be in UTC.  If the 3 or 4 hour difference is the difference in the time zones, then those numbers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out:
MP4 EXIF timestamps are indeed specified in UTC

What windows explorer displays, under the column "Date" is your machine's local time with respect to that UTC timestamp.

So it is impossible to sort MP4 and JPEG according to the "Date" column.
They will also be shown in wrong order in Photos app.